# Where can I ask questions about language structure?

Tags: discussion, languages

I want to ask why ruby and python don't handle the `variable++` notation, but I don't think it is a right place in StackOverflow. Where should I ask it?

Thanks

Comment: Already on SO: [Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717519/no-increment-operator-in-ruby), [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python). The former even has a quote from the language designer himself.